# Can I view persisten variables in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, simulink

I have a problem that I'm having a hard time even framing for this question's title.

I have a library that calculates the properties of refrigerants. For example, you give pressure and enthalpy, and it tells you the temperature. That library is coded in Fortran with a `mex` file to interface with Matlab. Now, I am 100% sure that library is thoroughly debugged (it was coded by people much smarter than me, and has been used for almost a decade). The problem is definitely in how I call it.

And that problem is this. I call the library from a `StartFcn` callback (a .m script file) in a subsystem of a simulink model. The first time I run this model, it runs perfectly. The values I'm sedning to the function are therefore correct. The second time I run it, however, it crashes. The inputs both times are exactly the same.

Also, if I do a `clear all` between the two runs, then there is no crash. But if I do only `clearvars` or `clear`, I still get a crash. When I debug and look at the variables being passed in the function call, they are valid and the same both times.

Does someone have any experience with this, or can advise me on what I might be doing wrong? Is there something persisting within the function call that only `clear all` can remove and not `clear`? Save My Soul!

Comment: At what point does it crash -- when starting, or at a later time in the simulation?

Comment: While starting. Actually, while compiling. So, there is a moment when the other things are compiled, but simulation hasn't started _yet_. At that point, the StartFcn script runs, but crashes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, persistent variables can be declared by the [persistent keyword](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/persistent.html).

If you want to clear only those, try

```
clear StartFcn
```

to clear all variables of the function `StartFcn`. A quote from the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/clear.html):

> If name is a function name, then clear name reinitializes any persistent variables in the function.

Comment: Thanks for replying. But in my case, the problem is that I want _nothing_ to persist in the memory, but things in the workspace to stay uncleared. Is there any way for doing that?

Comment: So, I tried `clearvars`, `clear -except varName` and `clear` (varName is a variable from base workspace which I DO need). Neither works. Only `clear all` works, unfortunately.

Comment: Try "clear StartFcn" -  this 'clears the function' and with it all persistent variables.

Comment: StartFcn is the generic name of the type of callback, it's not the name of the specific function that is causing the problem. However, even if `clear NameOfTheSpecificFunction` does work, it's better to work out why any persistence is causing a problem and address that issue.

Comment: You're absolutely right. Unfortunately, despite spending way too  much time trying to figure it out, I have been unable to make any headway and have been unable to find anyone else having a similar issue, due to the unique application that I'm using it in.

Answer (score 0):

A quick thing to try would be `clear mex` inbetween simulations - this should clear all the mex code from matlab.

Other questions to think about..

- Can you call the fortran interface directly from the matlab command line two times in a row?
- I believe that using a m-file sfunction to call fortran in simulink is quite inefficient.  Possibly consider writing your own fortran or C sfunction to interface to the code and compile in directly?
- in case you're using LoadLibrary to load fortran code compiled into a dll, are you calling FreeLibrary in the mdlTerminate function?

Hope some of this helps.

Comment: Hi @warren, I'm not too familiar with Simulink internally, but we have an installation package that installs the external library in Program Files. That library has it's own mex32 file that interfaces with Matlab. I personally do not have to load it each time, just do the 'Set Path' once. Is that what you meant?

Comment: also, `clear mex` doesn't seem to work. As for your questions, 1) Yes, I am able to call it twice from the command line, and most often, from Simulink as well 2) Usually, I also convert my matlab s-functions and function blocks to C++ s-functions for speed and efficiency, but haven't for this case, and 3) I guess I don't have to use LoadLibrary, as shown above

Answer (score 0):

I would try to put a `clear all` inside the function that you are calling in the StartFcn Callback.

So let's say your function is:

```
function [out] = nameoffunction(a,b,c)
%do calculation with a,b,c
d = a + b + c;

%output out
out = d;
assignin('base','out',d)
clear all
```

And you can call the function:

```
nameoffunction(a,b,c)
```

Let me know if it changes something. If this works, you could try other clear command but inside the function.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply. Yes, I would try that, but I have data in the base workspace that needs to be used by two subsystems, and both of them call the same script file in the `StartFcn`. So, I'm unable to do clear all. Also, I cannot do that _after_ a simulation either because I use output data then. Massive dilema!

Comment: @UnaEngineer The `clear all` inside your function won't clear your base workspace variables. It will clear the function workspace, which is different. It is not something to do, but since we don't have acces to your code, I'm curious to see what putting a `clear all` inside of your function would do.

Comment: I will definitely try this and reply back. Unfortunately, this problem is sometimes a pain to reproduce, and I have pressing deadlines this week. However, over the weekend, I plan on taking a hard look at this problem. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You are welcome. You can try simplifying your code and putting an example in your question. That could help us help you :)!